# Does std::string move assignment causes memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

Does the below program has memory leak ?

```
main()
{
std::string DD("paramhansa");
std::string SS("yogananda");

DD = std::move(SS);
}
```

Please consider string is large enough to be stored in heap.

What happened to the memory pointed by DD ?
Is it destroyed in the move assignment ?
Is this a memory leak ?

Comment: Moved out object will remain in destructible state. When it's time for it to go, the destructor will be called on `SS`, without effects on `DD` same for old value of `DD`, it is safely managed.

Comment: what evidence do you have that there would be a memory leak?

Comment: Why do you think standard library would allow for memory leaks in its implementation?

Comment: its the same as with `DD = SS;` the memory is mangaged by the `std::string`

Comment: so if the statement is like obj1 = std::move(obj2) ................ will the desctructor of obj1 be called ? automatically

Comment: _will the desctructor of obj1 be called_ No. The `obj1` is still alive and its destructor will be called as usually - if it goes out of scope. What happens inside `obj1` is another story and subject of the implementation of the move assignment operator of `obj1`.

Comment: `std::move` does not really move anything. It's just a cast that lets the "receiving end" take over ownership of any resources that the source might own. It does not either create or destroy anything in itself.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the below program has memory leak ?

No.

> Please consider string is large enough to be stored in heap.

Still no leak.

> What happened to the memory pointed by DD ?

Just to clarify: `DD` isn't a pointer. Sure, it may contain pointers as members that may point to something.

> Is it destroyed in the move assignment ?

The assignment operator of std::string may deallocate any memory that the class has previously allocated.

> Is this a memory leak ?

No.

> so if the statement is like obj1 = std::move(obj2) ................ will the desctructor of obj1 be called ? automatically

No. An assignment operator will be called.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it destroyed in the move assignment ?

Yes.

> Is this a memory leak ?

No.

The move assignment operator of std::string is in charge of making sure there is no leak in this case.

Unless of course your implementation of the standard library has a bug.

Comment: so if the statement is like 
obj1 = std::move(obj2) ................ will the desctructor of obj1 be called ? automatically

Comment: The old string memory of obj1 is freed at that point (but no destructor is called). The destructors are called when the function return, and obj1 will free its new string, and obj2 will free nothing since it is now empty

Comment: @RishiN No. It is the task of the move assignment operator to manage the resources of `obj1` and `obj2` such that no resource leak occurs.

Comment: thank u........ c++ is a complex language, could be the reason why ppl are moving away from it

Comment: It is not guaranteed the memory will be released in the *move assignment*. For example, one implementation might simply *swap the internal pointers* of the two strings.

Comment: @RishiN i am curious what you mean with "ppl are moving away from it". I don't know the numbers, but I rather have the feeling that since C++11 and newer standards there is renewed interest in C++.

Comment: @RishiN most of the commonly used languages are complex languages, the pitfalls and complexity might just manifest in different ways. Some languages are seemingly easier to used and to learn because they hide some complexity (like JavaScript, Python, Swift, …). But the fact that you get results easier with one language does not mean that you use the language correctly, it often just means that the language is more forgiving and obscures the fact that you are actually using the languages not correctly.